# NLP Generate Collection

Tags: nlp

I am working on of the hands on and expected output is

[('fans', 3), ('car', 3), ('disciplines', 1)]

['sports car', 'sports fans']

My code is below. I am able to get first expected output but not able to get second output correctly. could any one help me what is wrong here

```
    from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
    text='Thirty-five sports disciplines and four cultural activities will be offered during seven days of competitions. He skated with charisma, changing from one gear to another, from one direction to another, faster than a sports car. Armchair sports fans settling down to watch the Olympic Games could be for the high jump if they do not pay their TV licence fee. Such invitationals will attract more viewership for sports fans by sparking interest among sports fans. She barely noticed a flashy sports car almost run them over, until Eddie lunged forward and grabbed her body away. And he flatters the mother and she kind of gets prissy and he talks her into going for a ride in the sports car.'
    word='sports'
    tokenizedword = nltk.tokenize.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern = '\w*', gaps = False)
    #Step 2
    tokenizedwords = [x.lower() for x in tokenizedword if x != '']

    tokenizedwordsbigram=list(nltk.bigrams(tokenizedwords))
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
    filteredwords = []
    for x in tokenizedwordsbigram:
       if x not in stop_words:
          filteredwords.append(x)
     
    tokenizednonstopwordsbigram = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(filteredwords)  
    print(tokenizednonstopwordsbigram[word].most_common(3))
    gen_text=nltk.Text(tokenizedwords)
    print(gen_text.collocations())
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran code with adding the needed import `nltk import` and `from nltk.corpus import stopwords` and got the below output.

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

# use to find bigrams, which are pairs of words

text = \
    'Thirty-five sports disciplines and four cultural activities will be offered during seven days of competitions. He skated with charisma, changing from one gear to another, from one direction to another, faster than a sports car. Armchair sports fans settling down to watch the Olympic Games could be for the high jump if they do not pay their TV licence fee. Such invitationals will attract more viewership for sports fans by sparking interest among sports fans. She barely noticed a flashy sports car almost run them over, until Eddie lunged forward and grabbed her body away. And he flatters the mother and she kind of gets prissy and he talks her into going for a ride in the sports car.'
word = 'sports'
tokenizedword = nltk.tokenize.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern='\w*',
        gaps=False)

# Step 2
tokenizedwords = [x.lower() for x in tokenizedword if x != '']

tokenizedwordsbigram = list(nltk.bigrams(tokenizedwords))
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filteredwords = []

for x in tokenizedwordsbigram:
    if x not in stop_words:
        filteredwords.append(x)

tokenizednonstopwordsbigram = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(filteredwords)
print tokenizednonstopwordsbigram[word].most_common(3)

gen_text = nltk.Text(tokenizedwords)
print gen_text.collocations()
```

Here is the output:

```
[('car', 3), ('fans', 3), ('disciplines', 1)]
sports car; sports fans
None
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the same output as you got in jupyter note but my handson i am running hackerrank and i am getting below error -->
 collectionwords=gen_text.collocations()
  File "/var/ml/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/text.py", line 444, in collocations
    w1 + " " + w2 for w1, w2 in self.collocation_list(num, window_size)
  File "/var/ml/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/text.py", line 444, in <listcomp>
    w1 + " " + w2 for w1, w2 in self.collocation_list(num, window_size)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```py
print(gen_text.collocations())
```

with

```py
print(gen_text.collocation_list())
```

Your program will work fine

Answer (score 0):

gen_text = nltk.Text(tokenizedwords).collocation_list()

b=[i[0]+" "+i[1] for i in gen_text]

return b

you will the output as :

['sports car', 'sports fans']

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def performBigramsAndCollocations(textcontent, word):
    stop_words=set(stopwords.words('english'))
    pattern =r'\w+'
    tokenizewords=nltk.regexp_tokenize(textcontent,pattern)
    tokenizewords=[word.lower() for word in tokenizewords]
    tokenizewordsbiagrams=nltk.bigrams(tokenizewords)
    tokenizednonstopwordbigrams=[(w1,w2) for w1,w2 in tokenizewordsbiagrams if w1 not in stop_words and w2 not in stop_words]
    cfd_bigrams=nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(tokenizednonstopwordbigrams)
    cfd_bigrams=cfd_bigrams[word]
    mostfrequentwordafter=cfd_bigrams.most_common(3)
    collocationwords=nltk.Text(tokenizewords)
    collocationwords=collocationwords.collocation_list()
    collocationwords=[i[0]+" "+i[1] for i in collocationwords]
    
    return mostfrequentwordafter,collocationwords
```

You can try this . It works for me !

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it